# How to Disable FullScreen Button on react Native Expo video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, video-player, expo-av

Hi Everyone am new to `React Native` and `expo` am Trying to make video work in LANDSCAPE mode with default fullscreen video size i achieved that but

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect,  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';
import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg";
import * as NavigationBar from 'expo-navigation-bar';



export default function VideoPlayer() {
  // UseEffect function To check if backbutton is clicked if so DISPLAY BUTTOM NAVIGATION
  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync("visible"); })
    return () => backHandler.remove()
  }, [])
  

  // Hide Default Android Navigation Bar
  NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync("hidden");
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // Playing Video Status 
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

  // Show/Hide Video Controllers + Goback Custom Button
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);
  const toggleControls = useCallback(() => {
    setShowControls((showControls) => !showControls);
  }, []);

 

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={styles.container} onPress={() => toggleControls()}>
      { /* Video Player Container Button */ }
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />
      <View style={{ display: showControls ? 'flex' : 'none' , position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 10, zIndex: 500, elevation: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row', borderColor: "#333", borderWidth: .5, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.4)' }} onPress={() => { navigation.goBack();  NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync("visible"); }} >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontFamily: 'NotoKufiArabic_700Bold', fontSize: 11, marginRight: 10 }}>العودة الى الحلقة</Text>
          <Svg width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <Path fill="#fff" d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-1.568 18.005l-1.414-1.415 4.574-4.59-4.574-4.579 1.414-1.416 5.988 5.995-5.988 6.005z" />
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
      </View>
          { /* Video Player  */ }
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: '100%' }}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls={showControls}
        shouldPlay
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#050505',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});
```

the fullscreen button is still in display which i don't want to be displayed my code is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

To remove the fullscreen you have to remove `useNativeControls={showControls}`
and to handle video playback you can add something like this  `onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}` where `onPlaybackStatusUpdate` is something like this:

```
const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (newStatus) => {
  setStatus(newStatus);
}
```

These changes remove the native controls and allow you to create custom controls for your video. You can now design and implement your own controls however you want them to act.